# redirect subdir with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect this way:

```
http://domain.com/XXXXXX (6 chars letters and numbers);
```

to:

```
http://domain.com/coupon/XXXXXX
```

and keep url like above.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w\d]{6})\/?$ /coupon/$1/
```